Can remoteproc framework be used from inside a docker container?
The remoteproc framework can be used to load firmware to a remote processor or attach to it.
As remotepoc resides inside the kernel, would a docker container with correct privileges be able to use this framework to load firmware to a remote processor and start it accordingly?

It’s unclear if you want to jailbreak functionality here, I mean if you want to load firmware for the host system from a guest. I believe it’s impossible. Otherwise as long as host system allows you to access that remote microprocessor, you can do whatever you want in the guest.

I'd want to load a remote microprocessor from the host processor, so it is just a case of privileges of the container?
